# How to slice multidimensional array with Numpy, multiple columns?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am generating multidimensional array of different sizes, though they'll all have an even number of columns.

```
>> import numpy as np
>> x = np.arange(24).reshape((3,8))
```

Which results in:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

I am able to slice with numpy and get the first column in an array:

```
>> newarr = x[0:,0:2]

array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 8,  9],
       [16, 17]])
```

However, I want to have one array that is just a list of the columns where column 1 and 2 are together, 3 and 4 are together, and so on..  For example:

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
       [ 8,  9],
       [16, 17]],
       [[ 2,  3],
       [10, 11],
       [18, 19]],
       etc....]
)
```

This code below works but it's clunky and my arrays are not all the same.  Some arrays have 16 columns, some have 34, some have 50, etc.

```
>> newarr = [x[0:,0:2]]+[x[0:,2:4]]+[x[0:,4:6]]

[array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 8,  9],
       [16, 17]]), array([[ 2,  3],
       [10, 11],
       [18, 19]])]
```

There's got to be a better way to do this than

```
newarr = [x[0:,0:2]]+[x[0:,2:4]]+[x[0:,4:6]]+...+[x[0:,n:n+2]]
```

Help!

Comment: With numpy slicing there is an option called the step which is formatted as such `[start:stop:step]`. One example of this is that if you wanted to get every nth column you could do `[::n]`. This seems relevant to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is adding a `for loop`:

```
slice_len = 2
x_list = [x[0:, slice_len*i:slice_len*(i+1)] for i in range(x.shape[1] // slice_len)]
```

Output:

```
[array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 8,  9],
        [16, 17]]), array([[ 2,  3],
        [10, 11],
        [18, 19]]), array([[ 4,  5],
        [12, 13],
        [20, 21]]), array([[ 6,  7],
        [14, 15],
        [22, 23]])]
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Tuffknitz That's good to be helpful. But you should be careful that when the column size is odd, the number in `range` should plus one, i.e. `range(x.shape[1] // slice_len + 1)` so maybe there also need a `if ... else...`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments :) I have a check early on in the code that validates this array - if it's an odd number of columns then something is wrong and it will throw an exception.